# how to remove the json format from ui-select2 selected value and just display the value

Tags: json, angularjs, ui-select2

I have a ui-select2 select and it works fine but I need the selected values to be formatted like this value,value,value. I have it almost there. its returning ["value","value","value"]. I there a way to parse the [" "," "] out of my value?

```
<select ui-select2 multiple ng-model="selectedDa.value" data-placeholder="Select DA/'s" ngchange="updateDa()">
<option ng-repeat="da in da's" value="{{da.value}}> {{da.label}}>/option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have similar application which uses select2 and I'm actually doing this in my `.php` file (which is called by an Angular service through `$http`:

```
$inputGet = $_GET['chosenValues'];
$query = explode(",", $inputGet);
```

This `explode` PHP function breaks the string into pieces on the given character (in this/our case it's ",") and the resulting `$query` variable is actually an array - `array('value1','value2','value3',....);`